# Maps on iOS: Drawing layers without showing the base map

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-graphics, mapkit

We are looking for a drawing / mapping SDK for iOS with the following requirements:

- Draw multiple polygons on a single view. polygon coordinates are based on earth lat/long
- Do not show other map layers from satellite / street view / whatever - just the polygon data
- Allow adding layers / text/ bubbles / etc.
- Allow zoom in-out
- Allow clicking on regions.
- Calculate bounding rect automatically, and do not allow the user to scroll out of this area.

Is there an SDK that supports these requirements?

Thanks.

Comment: I think there are probably 2 popular choices. 1. Apple Mapkit 2. Google Map for iOS. You will have to read the documentation to understand if what you need are inside: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find in both any mention on how to hide the base map and/or constrain the scrolling. Maybe a mapping framework is an overkill - I only need to draw some polygons and layers...

Comment: For Apple maps you could add a tiled overlay that shows solid black tiles? That would hide the map although its possible you might briefly see the underlying map - I've only done this pulling tiles from server rather than being able to create immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk). It's open source, allows you to hide the basemap (or create a custom basemap to whatever appearance you desire), constrain the panning and zooming, add vector polygons atop the baselayer(s), add text and labels, control interactivity, and more.

Comment: Can you please give some advice how you can add a UILabel to the map (text)?

Comment: it is no longer open source. Use the [maplibre-gl fork](https://github.com/MapLibre/maplibre-gl-js) if you are interested in an Open Source solution